# Json Url.Action failing in new MVC 5 app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

I've made extensive use of `return Json(new { url = Url.Action("MyAction", new { param = 1 }` in my apps. I recently migrated an MVC 4 app to MVC 5 and it still works but if I build a new MVC app with Visual Studio 2013 update 2 (which templates a MVC 5, EF 6.1 and Identity 2 app) it now fails to redirect and the json is sent to the browser:

`Do you want to open or save 23xdf543v.json (28 bytes) from localhost`

(To get Identity 2 setup I created a new MVC 5 app and  copied all my MVC 4 app files into it and refactored to get it working).

If I open the JSON the url appears to be properly formatted. (in this example the MyAction is in MyController)

```
{"url":"/MyController/MyAction/1"}.
```

The odd thing is that it works with a migrated MVC 4 to MVC 5 app but not a newly templated MVC 5 app.

Action:

```
public ActionResult Phn2Add(PhoneVm vM)
{ 
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  { 
    _db.Phones.Add(vM.Phone); _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Details", new { id = vM.DetailsId }) });
  }
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErMsInvldEdt);
  PhTyDrpDwn();
  return PartialView("Add_Del/_PhnAdd", vM);
}
```

View:

```
@model MyApplicaiton.ViewModels.PhoneVm
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Add"; } 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onSuccess = function (result) { if (result.url) { window.location.href = result.url; } }
</script>
<div id="PhnAdd">
  <div style="padding-left:17px">
    <h3>Add a @Model.Msg? @Html.ActionLink("CANCEL", null, new { id = Model.DetailsId }) </h3>
  </div>
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(@Model.ActnNm, new AjaxOptions
    { 
      OnSuccess = "onSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "PhnAdd", HttpMethod = "Post"
    }))
    {  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
      <fieldset>      <legend></legend><br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Phone.PersonId) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DetailsId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActnNm) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Msg)
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th><span class="editor-label">Number: (7573334444)</span></th>
            <td>
              <span class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone.Number) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone.Number) </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><span class="editor-label">Type: Land or Mobile</span></th>
             <td><span class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("Phone.Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._PhTyp)
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone.Type) </span>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </fieldset>
    }
  </div>
```

Does MVC 5 handle `Url.Action` differently?  Is there some change in javascript's handling of `OnSuccess`? Is there a setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: The JSON returned looks fine to me. What did it look like before? Did you return it in an Ajax call, and now just to the browser directly?

Comment: It is being used in numerous of my controller Actions in conjunction with AJax.BeginForm's in my views. The code is identical between the MVC 4, migrated to MVC 5 and newly templated MVC 5 apps.  I have changed nothing.

Comment: That doesn't add up. Can you please share a very simple repro of your code, one controller action (or two to include the initial view) and one view? My guess is that you are trying to serve the json as a page rather than as Ajax. But since you say it's all the same, a sample can show what is going on

Comment: I agree, it's not making sense.  I've added an Action and View to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2013, update 2, MVC template doesn't install the `jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js` script.  I Added it in my BundleConfig but it wasn't installed in the Script folder.  Once installed the AjaxOnSuccess started working.

Answer (score 0):

These two scripts were dropped from the templates in VS2013. I've talked to the editor/template team, and we will update here when I get more info on the plan.

Comment: Your correct in that I had RC installed.  I just installed the final release of Update 2 and the MVC template still does not install the jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js script.

Comment: Yeah, I was confusing another script that was removed (jQuery validation). I talked to the right folks in the template team, and we are going to take a look and see if we want to bring it back.

Comment: The template installs jquery.validate.js but not the jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js and jquery-ui.js.  I had to manually install both of those.

Comment: yeah, we are taking a look, I'll update when I know more. In the meantime I'm editing the answer